# Boost installation and library paths

Tags: c++, boost

I have been using Boost (the header only library part) for sometime now. I recently started on a project that required the compiled libraries (filesystem etc).

I followed the instructions given in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#easy-build-and-install), and was under the impression that the libraries to installed (directly) in the usr/local folder.  After a lot of trial and error, I found that the correct (*.a) files to use were in:

/usr/local/boost_1_45_0/stage/lib/

Is this the correct folder to use for linking the boost built shlibs (shared libraries)?

Comment: yes , this is the correct path where boost libs are stored.

Comment: It depends how they were installed. Did you build from source or install from a package manager like apt or yum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example for linking regex static(*.a) lib:

g++ -I /usr/local/boost_1_45_0 -c your_regex_prog

g++ -static -o static_regex your_regex_prog.o -lboost_regex